# How do I programmatically render a menu's label?

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I'm trying to render out a menu with its label in Drupal 8. I am able to get the menu and its links inside of a preprocess function using a helper function, but I can't locate the menu's title.

Here is how I'm getting the menu. I'm able to add the return value as a twig variable $variable['menu']['menu-name'] and render out an `<ul>` anywhere I need to.

```
function get_menu($menu_name) {
  $menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
  $parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);
  $tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);
  $manipulators = array(
    // Only show links that are accessible for the current user.
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
    // Use the default sorting of menu links.
    array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
  );
  $tree = $menu_tree->transform($tree, $manipulators);
  $menu = $menu_tree->build($tree);

  return array('#markup' => drupal_render($menu));
}
```

Comment: Btw. You should use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` instead of `drupal_render()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the snippet to change the menu name:

```
 function example_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
      $element = &$variables['items'];
      foreach ($element as &$item) {
        if ($item['original_link']->getMenuName() == 'menu-machine-name') {
        //For the menu label    
       $menu = entity_load('menu', 'menu-machine-name');
          $menu_label = $menu->label(); 
          if ($item['title'] == 'Example menu') {
            $item['title'] = 'New menu name';
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Shreya, this will get the menu's machine name from a menu link and allow you to change the link's text, but it does not show me the menu's label/title.

Comment: if you print $item['title'] you will get the title of menu

Comment: If I dump my $menu['#items']['title'] it's only the title of the link, not the menu.

Comment: You want the menu name not the menu link is it ??

Comment: Yes. I'm passing the menu's machine name to the get_menu() function in my question. It's returning a renderable version of the menu's items. I am trying to also capture and output the menu's name as a label/header for it on my page. Thanks for being helpful.

Comment: $menu = entity_load('menu', 'admin');
$menu_label = $menu->label(); updated the answer as well